# How get Session info or current culture info on non page behind wrapper class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Main.Master page with buttons that set CultureInfo and store it in session:

```
protected void RU_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Session["MyCulture"] = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-Ru");
    Server.Transfer(Request.Url.LocalPath);     
}

protected void USA_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Session["MyCulture"] = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-AU");
    Server.Transfer(Request.Url.LocalPath);  
}
```

I write I non page behind wrapper class and in this class I need to get this Culture from session. I try on this class get current culture info like this:

```
(CultureInfo)HttpContext.Current.Session["MyCulture"]
```

But `HttpContext.Current` is NULL! How fix this???

Comment: this code is small .....plz more explain.it is not possiable

Comment: Where is this "non page behind wrapper class"?

Comment: I have a project for creating a C# class library (.dll) (.NET Framework 3.5) in my solution with classes. In one class I try to get a current culture info. How I can get it??

Answer (score 1):

If your class does not inherit from Page or a UserControl, then you should probably pass the current Context as a parameter to the method that needs to use it.

Also, if your class is an ASHX page, then you need to indicate that the page implements [System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx).

Comment: Not strictly true, but it wouldn't hurt

Comment: Good point. I have updated the answer to indicate that this is something that you should probably do (so that the class doesn't make any assumptions about the context in which it is being executed).

Answer (score 1):

I assume the code which accesses `HttpContent.Current` is running on a spearate thread to the ASP.NET thread.

If this is the case then then `HttpContent.Current` will not be available, and as such it is probably better to pass any dependent objects (such as the current culture)in to the new thread, rather than relying on access to the current HttpContext object.